# Get month name and year after week from datetime in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP website. I want to display month names like - Jan, Feb, Dec etc after a week 7 days ago.  I am using a function to display DateTime in a past ago format.

```
public function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);

    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

It's giving me like  -  `5 seconds ago,  5 days ago, 5 weeks ago, and months, year ago`.
But I want like -

```
5 seconds ago, 7 days ago then after 7 days should return like - 5 Jan 
and if the year is not the current year then display like - 5 Jan 2022
```

I have a column `created date  datetime .`

How can I return any seconds, any days, any Jan, any Jan 2022?

Comment: Where have you tried to change the code to fit with what you want?  What problems did you have?

Comment: I have mentioned the code above.

Comment: The code above doesn't show where you have tried to change it to fit what you want.  You say yourself that it doesn't show the right output, but not how you have tried to change it to make it work with what you do want.

Comment: I am a beginner of PHP. That's why I posted here to learn and understand next-level skills. I googled for that but didn't get any solution or reference for this type of operation.

Comment: Not every answer can be found by google alone, sometimes you have to write code for yourself.  For me stackoverflow is about helping people and not just writing the code for them.

Comment: I know about StackOverflow. I don't want code. I want a path to do that. A simple process not code, text reference, guide.  This is called help.

Comment: Try something like `if($ago->diff($now)->days > 7)` - find out more in the [php manual on DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a method to do that by if condition. It will be helpful for others.
Create a condition like -

```
if($ago->diff($now)->days > 6) 
{
return your desired date format like - 5 Jan or 5 Jan 2022
}
else 
{ 
 return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now'; 
}
```

After a week, it will display your desired format.